# Finding Sample Size

Tags: r, sampling, confidence-interval

I am attempting to use several methods (Wald, Wilson, Clopper-Pearson, Jeffreys, etc.) to calculate sample sizes for confidence intervals. I have been unable to find, in R, how to calculate these. Is there a better way to calculate these besides brute force? Does R have a package that will output all to compare?

I have been unsuccessful with the likes of `n.clopper.pearson{GenBinomApps}` and some of these require lots of by-hand computations. I have done this for the Wald method:

```
#Variables
z <- 1.95996
d <- .05    
p <- 0.5
q <- 1 - p

#Wald
n_wald <- (z^2 * (p*q))/(d^2)
n_wald
```

But, I have not been able to find away, besides guess and check methods, to produce the others in R.

Comment: I'm not going to flag your question but technically asking for a library is considered a software recommendation request and is off topic for SO. There's another SE site for that.  Anyway are you asking for power analysis? The most common package for that is `pwr` if you're not going to do it manually. http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html However for Wald, Wilson, etc use `PropCls` or `binom`

Comment: @Hack-R no I am asking for actual sample size calculations in R . I have found some that do an average job (n.clopper.pearson{GenBinomApps}) but I was hoping someone could help me not have to use brute force with each one. I am not asking for a specific software recommendation but for help in R, as I am relatively new to it, in finding how to calculate these easily

Comment: As a generalization, if you have a function to calculate either the margin of error (confidence intervals) or the power (hypothesis tests), you have  what you need to calculate the sample size.  If you can solve for `n`, then you can write a function to calculate `n` without relying on brute force.  Not all equations can be solved, however.  My experience has been that using the `optimize` function to solve these equations gives the best results.  You can see some of my work in a GitHub repository I've been unable to continue working on for some time. https://github.com/nutterb/StudyPlanning

Comment: @a.powell I'm sorry, what do you mean "actual sample size"? If you mean determining the sample size you need to estimate an effect with a given level of certainty, then that's power analysis and the tools I mentioned above should be what you need. If you mean "how do I sample a certain number of people" then you can do that with `sample_n` or `sample_frac` from `dplyr`. I think you mean power analysis and maybe didn't know that's what it was called; if so just go back to my earlier comment.

Comment: @Hack-R sorry, yes you were correct. The binom package was extremely helpful and got me most of the way there.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you. This code is extremely helpful and saves much time

Comment: @a.powell Awesome :)

Comment: @a.powell, if you've managed to solve your own problem based on the comments, you're encouraged to post your solution as an answer (self-answering is fine/encouraged on SO)

Comment: @BenBolker I will gladly do that, but being new to SO I am unsure how. Advice?

Comment: you have to wait for some more high-rep users to vote to re-open your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question with help from the comments:

```
n_wald <- ciss.wald(p, d, alpha = 0.05)
n_wilson <- ciss.wilson(p, d, alpha = 0.05)
n_agricoull <- ciss.agresticoull(p, d, alpha = 0.05)
```

These were from the binomSamSize package. Still struggling with an optimization for the clopper-pearson and jeffries if anyone can provide direction there, but these commands calculated sample size easily.